# Dlib object / face detector - refined fhog scanning instead of sliding window

Tags: dlib

I'm using dlib's API in python. The functions `get_frontal_face_detector()` and `simple_object_detector()` both appear to use the function `scan_fhog_pyramid()` which apparently creates several scales of the image, and then applies HOG detectors in a sliding window fashion.

Is it possible to use the Dlib library but instead of using a sliding window, scan for ROI in specific (prederemined) locations? Does anyone have any experience in this and can point where in the file `scan_fhog_pyramid()` this can be modified?

Alternatively, I could write my own function but I do not have access to Dlib's HOG detector. Is it possible to run just the detector and linear classifier on my own, without using the `scan_fhog_pyramid()` function to find ROIs?

I hope my question is clear enough...

Thanks.